# BeautifulSoup Webscraping Text overflows the cell and goes to next one. I want to keep the information in one cell instead of separated

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Beginner here trying to get this down. I feel like the solution is very easy at this point as I have tried numerous things but none of it worked. I've been trying this for the whole day with no avail. I tried looking on stack but was unable to find the answer.

I'm trying to scrape the date text and the deal post from spoofee.com

The format is Date and then Info about the deal. I tried to do that but failed miserably as the text overflowed to next cells. Tried bunch of solutions but none worked. First I'm trying to write the Date and the Title of the Deal. Once I'm able to accomplish that I will do the Info.

Here's my Code.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html_url = 'http://www.spoofee.com/'

uClient = uReq(html_url)

page_html = uClient.read()

uClient.close()

page_soup = bs(page_html, 'html.parser')

titles = page_soup.findAll("td",{"class":"dealtitle"})
date = page_soup.findAll("td",{"class":"date"})

filename = "spoofeedeals.csv"
f = open(filename,"w")

headers = "Date and Deals\n"
f.write(headers)

for day in date:
    f.write('\n'+day.text+'\n\n')
    for title in titles:
        f.write(title.text+'\n')

f.close()
```

This is what I get.

[Resulting data in csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ompMq.png)

How can I get the date to be in one cell and not the next two cells? I tried get_text(separator=",") but that didn't work. When I try other solutions, the rest of the info titles get screwed up. This is step 1 before going to my step 2 of pulling more data from this page but I'm stuck.

I have a feeling I'm going to get this with a easy solution that I'm going to facepalm myself.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date you're retrieving from that page is in the format

**Thursday, April 19th, 2018**

It contains two commas. Most software for converting input to a csv will split input records on those commas to yield separate cells. You have a few options.

- You could simply discard the commas from the date; this would be easiest, and the date would still be readable.
- When you call the software (such as pandas of csv) to produce the csv file you could set the separator to some character other than comma so that the commas in the date would be ignored. But if you need to add other fields you would have to remember to use the same special character to separate fields. And the special character you use would have to be one that does not appear elsewhere in the data. One of my favourites is '|'.

Comment: I've used the method you recommeded to replace the "," with "|" and it works. However, going forward, is there anyway I would be able to have the date in the format with comma?

Comment: @uclaastro: What software are you using to read spoofeedeals.csv?

Comment: I'm just using Mac Numbers to open the files for now. However, I would be utilizing pandas in the future as I'm learning Python and webscraping

Comment: I don't know Mac Numbers. You read a csv with pandas using `read_csv`. It has a parameter `sep`. You can set that to '|', as suggested in my answer. Then you can leave the commas in the date.

Comment: Mac Numbers is kinda like Excel, just a spreadsheet. I will try reading it through pandas. Thank you